# How to set cookie through nginx reverse proxy (flask app)

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am writing an app in flask.
The test code for setting and getting the cookies is

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, render_template
from flask import request
from flask import Response
from flask import jsonify

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def index():
    resp = make_response("Setting cookie")
    resp.set_cookie("test", "hw", max_age = 3090, path='/', domain="127.0.0.1")

    return resp

@application.route("/test")
def test():
    return jsonify(request.cookies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

And if I run this without nginx (just on port 5000 from the command line) I am able to see the cookie set but as soon as I put it behind nginx the cookies refuse to set.  My nginx configuration is

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location /static {
        alias /srv/HackerNews/news/static/;
    }


    location /users {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/srv/HackerNews/backend/service.sock;
        uwsgi_param     SCRIPT_NAME /users;
        }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_cookie_path / /;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/srv/HackerNews/backend/service.sock;
        uwsgi_param     SCRIPT_NAME /;
        }
}
```

I have googled around for hours (where I learned of proxy_cookie_path) but nothing at all has worked for me.  The only other SO questions I've found that were similar go unanswered.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Just ran into something similar. But I learned that `proxy_cookie_path` does not work when you have `uwsgi_pass `. You can try using usual nginx `proxy_pass` instead